# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '__no_builder' in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So I have gotten this error when I was trying to run an example code for a github which creates a live plot of the mic data. The error is TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument '__no_builder'
I have tried changing    `def __init__(self,): super(Logic, self).__init__()` in to     `def __init__(self, **kwargs):  super(Logic, self).__init__(**kwargs)` this was recommended by someone in stack overflow but it did not work i am send ing the full code right here...
"""Real time plotting of Microphone level using kivy
"""

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot
from kivy.clock import Clock
from threading import Thread
import audioop
import pyaudio

def get_microphone_level():
    """
    source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478315/getting-volume-levels-from-pyaudio-for-use-in-arduino
    audioop.max alternative to audioop.rms
    """
    
    chunk = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 44100
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    s = p.open(format=FORMAT,
               channels=CHANNELS,
               rate=RATE,
               input=True,
               frames_per_buffer=chunk)
    global levels
    while True:
        data = s.read(chunk)
        mx = audioop.rms(data, 2)
        if len(levels) >= 100:
            levels = []
        levels.append(mx)


class Logic(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        super(Logic, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])

    def start(self):
        self.ids.graph.add_plot(self.plot)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.get_value, 0.001)

    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.get_value)

    def get_value(self, dt):
        self.plot.points = [(i, j/5) for i, j in enumerate(levels)]


class RealTimeMicrophone(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("look.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    levels = []  # store levels of microphone
    get_level_thread = Thread(target = get_microphone_level)
    get_level_thread.daemon = True
    get_level_thread.start()
    RealTimeMicrophone().run()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the full error traceback.

Comment: The cause of the error probably in the `look.kv`. Please post a runnable code.

Comment: @NattōsaiMitō Thanks ya it solved the problem

Comment: Can you share your solution as an answer here? That way your question can be helpful to others with the same issue (like me!)