# Why is the kivy builder is failng when trying to load the "Logic" widget from the file "look.kv" for the code included

Tags: python, numpy, audio, kivy

I'm getting TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument '__no_builder' in Kivy

I believe this is exactly the issue raised by abrartx on Nov 2 at 3:59, but there is not a clear answer to that question.  This code is downloaded from git hub and modified to use a pseudo random number rather than the audio level from the mic.

I'm using python 3.6.7 64bit with kivy on windows 10

I've worked through several dependency issues, but this one has me stuck.  It appears that the kivy builder is not able to build the "Logic" widget in the look.kv file.
Any help would be appreciated.  The code follows:

file: main.py

```
#Real time plotting of Microphone level using kivy

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.garden.graph import MeshLinePlot
from kivy.clock import Clock
from threading import Thread
#import audioop
#import pyaudio
import random

def get_fake_mic_level():
    #source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478315/getting-volume-levels-from-pyaudio-for-use-in-arduino
    #audioop.max alternative to audioop.rms

    global levels
    while True:
        mx = random.random()
        if len(levels) >= 100:
            levels = []
        levels.append(mx)


class Logic(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,):
        super(Logic, self).__init__()
        self.plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])

    def start(self):
        self.ids.graph.add_plot(self.plot)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.get_value, 0.001)

    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.get_value)

    def get_value(self, dt):
        self.plot.points = [(i, j/5) for i, j in enumerate(levels)]


class RealTimeMicrophone(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("look.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    levels = []  # store levels of microphone
    #get_level_thread = Thread(target = get_microphone_level)
    get_level_thread = Thread(target = get_fake_mic_level)
    get_level_thread.daemon = True
    get_level_thread.start()
    RealTimeMicrophone().run()
```

file: look.kv

```
#:import MeshLinePlot kivy.garden.graph.MeshLinePlot
Logic:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: [1, .8]
            Graph:
                id: graph
                xlabel: ""
                ylabel: "Level"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: [1, .2]
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Button:
                text: "START"
                bold: True
                on_press: root.start()
            Button:
                text: "STOP"
                bold: True
                on_press: root.stop()
```

Stack:

```
File "D:\00-Data\00-code\py\audio-graph\real-time-plot-microphone-kivy-master\main.py", line 78, in <module>
  RealTimeMicrophone().run()
File "E:\Programs\Python-3-6-7\Lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
  self._run_prepare()
File "E:\Programs\Python-3-6-7\Lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
  root = self.build()
File "D:\00-Data\00-code\py\audio-graph\real-time-plot-microphone-kivy-master\main.py", line 70, in build
  return Builder.load_file("look.kv")
File "E:\Programs\Python-3-6-7\Lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 306, in load_file
  return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
File "E:\Programs\Python-3-6-7\Lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 404, in load_string
  widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)(__no_builder=True)

builtins.TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '__no_builder'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle keyword arguments in the `__init__()` method for your `Logic` class. Like this:

```
class Logic(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Logic, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
```